# What resets the keyboard settings in Linux when you connect a USB keyboard?

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, xorg

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a file `keyb` with content to disable capslock (by turning it into mod3):

   ```
   add    mod3 = Mode_switch
   keycode  66 = Mode_switch
   ```
2. Use xmodmap to load it (ignore any errors, it should work anyway)

   ```
   xmodmap keyb
   ```
3. Press caps lock, confirm that it does not work like a regular caps lock anymore
4. Plug in an external USB keyboard. If this is a desktop machine, just unplug and re-plug the same keyboard.
5. Press caps locks. It's now back to it's normal state. Note that this is **NOT** a per-keyboard setting. Caps lock gets reset to its old state on **all** keyboards, not just on the newly plugged in one.

### What I expect to happen

My settings to remain the way I set them. What possible reason could there be for overwriting what the user set, with just some default?

### What I actually see

All keyboards are reset to default mappings when any new keyboard is connected.

### More…

The customizations get thrown away whether I set them with `xmodmap` or with `xkbcomp`.

Solutions to merely disable capslock somewhere else (e.g. Xorg config) won't help, since I have a huge set of customizations. This is just a simple demo showing that settings are in fact reset.

Ideally the fix should not need me to have root access (why would keyboard settings for a user be for root only?), but I would be very happy even for a solution that requires root.

I tried having a cronjob that would re-set my settings once a minute, but changing the settings freezes input for a while (for `xmodmap` for several seconds), so that didn't work.

My suspects are `udev` and `systemd` (`systemd` having its fingers in everything), but I've not been able to find what does this, and where. This has been a bug for years, and unfortunately I don't remember all things I've tried.

Re-setting my settings triggered on plugging in USB would be ok, but not great, since aside from the 100% reproducible steps above, it also happens "randomly" (maybe something restarts, or something).

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue since? I am still experiencing this on Manjaro on 2022.

Comment: No. I can't find the reference anymore, but if memory serves I had a core Xorg developer tell me that this is simply not fixable in X. I've since moved to Wayland, which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to Ubuntu bug report
[#1899206 : Input device settings not applied on hotplug/reconnect/resume in Xorg sessions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206)
from December 2020, the problem is with the package
`mutter` and should be fixed in version `3.38.2-1ubuntu1~20.10.1`.

Search for this version in your repository. If it's not found there yet, either wait
for it to arrive, or build it from source as described in the bug report.
If your distribution is not Ubuntu, you will have to adapt the instructions.

---

If the above doesn't work for you, an old bug report
[#295990 : Keyboard layout reset after attaching USB keyboard](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/295990)
may help with some workarounds.

Comment: The bug seems to be the same for both, according to the reports. But of course your problem might possibly not be related to either of these reports,

Comment: I can confirm that `udevadm trigger` breaks my keyboard config on its own (and locks input while doing so, just like re-fixing the layout). Instead of trying to race with udev it'd be nice if udev just minded its own business and never ever touched my keyboard layout.

Comment: That was also a [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/295990/comments/23) in the old bug report.

Comment: Yeah that's where I got it. Sigh, and [this old bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25262) seems to say that Xorg just plain does not support ANY kind of settings of ANY kind, and that overwriting the user's wishes is somehow working as intended.

Comment: There was [one workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/295990/comments/16) you could perhaps adapt. Another [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/295990/comments/25) says it does not occur when using Wayland instead of X.

Comment: There are various ways to re-apply the settings, but they have the drawback that they lock up all keyboard input for up to 10 seconds (depending on the size of your config). I'll look into switching to wayland. I don't quite know what implications that has.